# Android calendar: Best practices for using a stock calendar or creating another for one's app?

Tags: android, calendar

I am going to have a user enter an event in my app that will then add that to the calendar in the Android system. From reading and checking the calendars on my tablet I find that there are a number of calendars and the ability to add more. For example, here's what I find on my tablet (from LogCat):

```
D/AccessCalendar: There are 4 calendars on this phone
D/AccessCalendar: There are 35 columns in the calendar cursor
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 0's account name is: user_name@gmail.com
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 0's display_name is: Holidays in United States
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 0's name is: Holidays in United States
D/AccessCalendar: and it's ID is: 2
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 1's account name is: user_name@gmail.com
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 1's display_name is: Weather
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 1's name is: Weather
D/AccessCalendar: and it's ID is: 3
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 2's account name is: user_name@gmail.com
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 2's display_name is: user_name@gmail.com
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 2's name is: user_name@gmail.com
D/AccessCalendar: and it's ID is: 4
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 3's account name is: user_name@gmail.com
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 3's display_name is: Contacts
D/AccessCalendar: Calendar 3's name is: Contacts
D/AccessCalendar: and it's ID is: 5
```

My question is, should I create my own calendar for my app or should I use one already provided, such as the user_name@gmail.com calendar? What is the best practices for using calendars, create another or use an existing one?

Also, does Android use the various calendars as the source of information for the visible calendar; Do the various calendars populate one on-screen calendar?

I am using [Calendar provider overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider) as my primary reference but it doesn't discuss my question, at least that I can see. Any suggestions or links to information are appreciated. I've been searching and have come up empty.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to venture my own answers:

1. Best practices is to create a new calendar for your app, to segregate your calendar data from the other calendars in your device's calendar system. Do not use another calendar for your data.
2. It may seem obvious to others, but I have come to the conclusion that the calendar system is designed to use multiple calendars that display their individual data on the Google Calendar app along with all other calendars. Each calendar, such as yours, needs to be added to the Google Calendar app for display. It would be nice if [Calendar provider overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider) had a short discussion of this to help guide new developers along the path of best practices.

As a resource, I found this post very informative: [Android Calendar: how to write sync adapter for calendar INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360073/android-calendar-how-to-write-sync-adapter-for-calendar-insert)

And this post confirmed what I thought how it could be done: [How can I add a new phone calendar to Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881851/how-can-i-add-a-new-phone-calendar-to-android?noredirect=1&lq=1). It also filled in a number of holes, things that I hadn't a clue about, such as buildUpon() and Uri result = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(calendarsUri, values.

I was able to successfully add a local calendar for use by my app that shows up on Google Calendar! I hope that this helps others who want to create their own calendar for their own app.